# "Localization failed to read a strings file"

Tags: ios, swift, localization

Suddenly I get the mentioned message when trying to export for localization, I've checked the system log, but nothing seems to stand out. I might removed a strings-file using the storyboard to uncheck, but not delete. How to solve this?

Comment: need more detail of your query